# How to programmatically query the translated content of a block in drupal9

Tags: php, drupal

I created a block, the default language is English and the translation language is Chinese. Now I query the content of this block in my code:

```
$block = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('block_content')
      ->loadByProperties([
        'info' => $info,
        'langcode' => 'zh-hant'
      ]);
```

But what I got is still in English, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to load the `block_content` entities without langcode condition, then get the translation in the language you need by `getTranslation()`:

```php
$blocks = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('block_content')
  ->loadByProperties([
    'info' => $info
  ]);
$translated_blocks = array_map(function ($block) {
  return $block->getTranslation('zh-hant');
}, $blocks);
// do somthing with $translated_blocks
```